# WebClient freeze after download

Tags: c#, networking, webclient

I'm facing another problem, my application downloads a file from a web, extracts it, deletes it and so on, it runs fine for the first run, then when it comes to downloading the next file it simply freezes the download and hangs there forever.. It's probably something with trying to open an already open connection, but I have no idea how to close it, this is my first time networking with C# and I'm self teaching.

My code:

```
  public void start() {
        if (File.Exists("Data/version.txt")) { File.Delete("Data/version.txt"); }
        label1.Text = "Getting update information...";
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        webClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("http://127.0.0.1/update/version.txt"), @"Data/version.txt");
        webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(versionCompleted);
    }

    private void versioncheck() {
        if (File.Exists("Main.exe"))
        {       
            label1.Text = "Contacting update server...";
                var versionInfo = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo("Main.exe");
                string version = versionInfo.ProductVersion;
                string[] nversion = version.Split('.');
                string updateversion = nversion[3];

                int version = Int32.Parse(updateversion);
                ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("Data/version.txt");
                ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                string readline = sr.ReadLine();
                sr.Dispose();
                int serverversion = Int32.Parse(readline);

                if (serverversion > version) {
                    string filenumber = (version+1).ToString();
                    downloadfile(filenumber); 
                }
                else if(serverversion == version){
                    label1.Text = "Game is up to date!";
                    startButton.Enabled = true;
                }

        }
        else { MessageBox.Show("Unexpected Error!", "Error!"); }
    }

    private void ProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    }

    private void Completed(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = "Extracting Files...";
        var versionInfo = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo("Main.exe");
        string version = versionInfo.ProductVersion;
        string[] nversion = version.Split('.');
        string updateversion = nversion[3];
        int version = Int32.Parse(updateversion); string nversion = (version + 1).ToString();

        Process proc = Process.Start("update"+nversion+".exe"); // extract in the silent mode
        proc.WaitForExit();
        File.Delete("update" + nversion + ".exe");
        label1.Text = "Checking for more updates...";
        versioncheck();
    }

    private void versionCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e) {
        versioncheck();
    }

    private void downloadfile(string filenumber)
    {
        try
        {
            //MessageBox.Show("Download working");
            System.Net.WebClient webClient = new System.Net.WebClient();
            webClient.OpenRead("http://127.0.0.1/Update/update" + filenumber + ".exe");
            Int64 bytes_total = Convert.ToInt64(webClient.ResponseHeaders["Content-Length"]);
            string updatelength = Convert.ToString((bytes_total / 1024).ToString());
            label2.Text = "File size:" + updatelength + "KB";
            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            label1.Text = "Downloading Update...";
            webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(ProgressChanged);
            webClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("http://127.0.0.1/Update/update" + filenumber + ".exe"), @"update"+filenumber+".exe");
            webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(Completed);
            webClient.Dispose();

        }
        catch (WebException )
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Connection error!", "Error!");
            Application.Exit();
        }
        catch (IOException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Unknown Error!", "Error!");
            Application.Exit() ;
        }       
    }
```

Comment: Can you breakpoint into versionCheck()? Does it get there? Is your form locked when the first download completes? I can't remember, but the `DownloadFileCompleted` event might call back into the main form thread if that's the case. Also, try moving the `DownloadFileCompleted` call to the line above `DownloadFileAsync`. This probably wont do anything considering the file might be large, but it's a good idea anyway.

Comment: Also, you're re-declaring variables as different types all over the place.

Comment: Yes I thought it would be easier to re-declare them instead of creating new ones with different names, just for the sake of not getting lost, I believe when I re-declare them, it gets rid of the older ones, am I wrong? please correct my mistakes if you may :)

And everything works, the thing is it's supposed to download 3 files in a row, it only downloads one and breaks when it starts to download the second one, it shows it's size = 0 bytes on the disk, untill I restart it.

Comment: No, your IDE should give you an error... You can't redeclare stuff like that. At least I can't anyway. What I would do is breakpoint the actual download and see what happens on the second iteration. I can't copy and paste your code (I tried) because you didn't provide your logic to start the download. Also, does your form freeze?

Comment: I just put start() in the form_load event, above that is the using System statements, and no it doesn't freeze, I can move it all around and close it with no problems at all.. the download just stops untill I restart it, downloads a file and then the same happens, I'll fix the declaration issue, no idea why it doesn't throw errors if it's supposed to.. I'm using VS 2010.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If u use async operation u gonne need to use the async and await keywords.

U need to dispose or close your webclient when it is done downloading or failing.

As b1tsh1ft stated best thing is to use the using statement.

```
string version = versionInfo.ProductVersion;
string[] nversion = version.Split('.');

int version = Int32.Parse(updateversion); 
string nversion = (version + 1).ToString();
```

Isn't your VS not giving a conflicting error in your editor about this ?

Comment: Nope not at all, that made me think it's like php, new value overrides old value, I understand it doesn't work that way now that you guys have said it.. I'll edit it and see how it works.

Answer (score 0):

First you should put WebClient in a using block because it implements IDisposable

```
using(var webClient = new WebClient())
{
    // do work here
    webClient.DownloadFile(..)
}
```

Don't use the async version. An exception is likely being thrown and is lost on the other thread. Test and make it work regularly first.

Also put your StreamReader (or anything implementing IDisposable) in a using() statement. It is more reliable then manually calling dispose because it disposes even on failure.

Comment: Does that mean that I should put the extraction part of the code after the using block? My main problem trying to do anything differently was that the extraction started before the download finished, that's why I used async, thanks for the information though, I'll try it :)